# Make 4 Divs align side by side using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, user-experience

So i am having a hard time aligning my cards side by side. They are a bunch of divs wrapped in lists under a `<ul>`

I am hesitant to chandge the display as it is vital for my responiveNESS. Changing the position is not helping.

i DONT want to change how it looks on mobile because it perfectly goes with my other elements. Maybe you can share some resources to help.

This is my html

```
        <ul class="cards">
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-5.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-2.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-6.png"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-1.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
/* Design */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.main-card{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 right: 10%;

}



img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
     border-radius: 10px; 
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #89B0D5  0%,  #E677F1   51%,  #9A669F   100%);
}


.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    margin: 8px 10px 12px;
}

.cards {
   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  list-style: none;
 position: relative;

}

.cards_item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 

  position: relative;

}

.card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white
}

.card_title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;

}

.card_text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;    
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Do you have any tips? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood your problem. You can remove display: flex; flex-direction: column;
from

```
.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  position: relative;
}
```

Then add

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding row and column like below.

```css
/* Design */

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 100%;
    flex: 50%;
  }
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.main-card{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 right: 10%;

}



img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
     border-radius: 10px; 
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #89B0D5  0%,  #E677F1   51%,  #9A669F   100%);
}


.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    margin: 8px 10px 12px;
}

.cards {
   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  list-style: none;
 position: relative;

}

.cards_item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 

  position: relative;

}

.card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white
}

.card_title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;

}

.card_text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;    
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
 
 <ul class="cards">
  <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-5.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid 
               
layout</p>

                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </li>
          </div>
<div class="column"> 
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-2.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
               
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
             
          </li>
          </div>
                <div class="column"> 
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-6.png"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </li>
         
</div>
<div class="column"> 
          <li class="cards_item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="./assets/Blog-post/post-1.jpg"></div>
              <div class="card_content">
                <h2 class="card_title">Card Grid Layout</h2>
                <p class="card_text">Demo of pixel perfect pure CSS simple responsive card grid layout</p>
                <button class="btn card_btn">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </li>
</div>
</div>

        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```